# How to migrate a function UploadItemFts(string folderId, byte[data]) on EWS managed api to Graph function

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm migrating EWS Managed api to Graph. When I use EWS Managed API, it has the function UploadItemFts(string folderId, byte[data]).
This function helps to move a message(it has all properties) from mailbox X to mailbox Y.

```
public string UploadItemFts(string folderId, byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {             
            UploadItem itemToUpload = new UploadItem(_service)
            {
                ParentFolderId = folderId,
                Data = data,
                CreateAction = CreateAction.CreateNew
            };

            var uploadItemResult = _service.UploadItem(itemToUpload);
            if (uploadItemResult.Result == ServiceResult.Success)
            {
                return uploadItemResult.Id.UniqueId;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception(uploadItemResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
        catch (ServiceResponseException srex)
        {
            string details = Shared.DumpServiceResponseException(srex);
            XLogger.Debug(this, string.Format("ExportMessageFTS >> ServiceResponseException >> {0}", details));
            throw new Exception(details);
        }
    }

    public UploadItemsResponse UploadItem(UploadItem item)
    {
        //XLogger.Audit(this, AuditCategory.Exchange, CommonUtils.GetLocalIPAddress(), "UploadItem({0})".FormatString(item?.Data));
        UploadItemsRequest request = new UploadItemsRequest(this, ServiceErrorHandling.ReturnErrors);

        request.Items = new UploadItem[] { item };
        
        return request.Execute()[0];
    }
```

I don't see any Graph API to support doing this. Could you guys have any recommendations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Graph does not support `UploadItems` operation or anything similar. You can try to work with the raw MIME source, but that will miss all MAPI-specific properties that are not mapped to MIME.

Comment: I can get the mime content of the message. But it cannot upload to another mailbox using the Graph Sendmail function because it requires permission mail.send.share from the message's sender. Of course, the message's sender is any mailbox.

Comment: Why do you need to use Sendmail? Can't you POST the message to `/messages`? But, again, you will lose MAPI specific properties unless the message is in theTNEF format.

Comment: I tried to post message with url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{toRecipientEmail}/messages. The message go to the Draft also. Because it needs the permission mail.send from the sender. I still don't know why EWS can upload the message.

Comment: Have you tried posting to `<folderid>/messages`?

Comment: I did also but nothing changed.

Comment: What did you mean nothing changed? Do you mean the message still ended up in the Drafts folder instead of the one you explicitly specified?

Comment: Yes. It goes to Drafts Folder as draft email